# How do I retrieve data from an external url using php?

Tags: php, json, xpath

This is the current code that I have in order to retrieve the sizes for a particular product, however when an item has multiple drop-downs such as this one does for color. You must first select the color before retrieving the sizes for that color. I will need to retrieve both sets of data; colors and sizes.

It seems if I am not mistaken that this site uses the JSON structure.

I am a VERY novice learner and would like guidance on what to do next in order to retrieve the data using php...

Thanks in advance! :)

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc ->loadHTMLFile('http://www.drjays.com/shop/P1543932/');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$size = $xpath->query('//*[contains(@class, \'product_dropdown\')]');

foreach ($size as $sizes)
{
    echo $sizes->nodeValue .PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

update: I was able to use Google Chrome (developer tools) to retrieve this information. I believe this is confirmation that it is in fact JSON.

```
"description" : "The Lace Inset Tie Front Woven Top by Apple Bottoms features:\r\n<br>\r\n<ul>\r\n<li> US sizing</li>\r\n<li> Pieced lace accents on shoulders</li>\r\n<li> Metal stud trim</li>\r\n<li> Two chest pockets</li>\r\n<li> Button-down closure</li>\r\n<li> Sleeveless cut</li>\r\n<li> Waist tie on front</li>\r\n\r\n<br>\r\n<b> Model is wearing size 1X</b>\r\n</ul>",
       "sizes" : [
          {
             "id" : "1533783",
             "display" : "1X"
          },
          {
             "id" : "

1533785",
         "display" : "2X"
      }
   ]
```

Comment: read function `file_get_contents`

Comment: Hi @moeed, I did try to use : $datadj = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://www.drjays.com/shop/P1543932/')); However when I var_dump($datadj); the result is NULL

Comment: @CuriousE Try `var_dump( file_get_contents( 'http://drjays.com/shop/P1543932' ) );`. Does it return what you think it should return? The JSON you put on this page is invalid json. It should have a `{` at the beginning and a `}` at the end. If that's the case, something like `var_dump( json_decode( '{' . file_get_contents('http://drjays.com/shop/P1543932/') . '}' ) );` will return an object. If you pass something that isn't valid JSON to `json_decode` it will return `NULL`.

Comment: @Sumurai8 the var_dump is currently working with Dennis' guidance utilizing 'sitejson?class=Shop&cmd=get_product' and moeed's guidance utilizing file_get_contents to retrieve the JSON data... my issue now is that the var_dump displays a long list of JSON data... I will update the intiial post to explain further. Thank you all for helping! I feel like I'm almost there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't think that is the url for the actual JSON object, with the google chrome developer tools can you find the object url?

Comment: hmm, the name seems to be called sitejson, when I hover over the name it reads http://www.drjays.com/sitejson Request URL:http://www.drjays.com/sitejson
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK -- I hope that's what you were asking for?

Comment: that doesn't seem to be it, what are you hovering over i would like to get to what you are looking at

Comment: I am in the "Network" tab, and I have the "XHR" tab on the bottom checked. When I clear all the requests and select a color from the product the name sitejson is displayed on the left and the initator is jscombined.js:4

Comment: alright so i think this is the url for get methods that retrieves the json http://drjays.com/sitejson?class=Shop&amp;cmd=add I am not sure what the parameters are but they are a good start. You are going to have to figure out what info goes where. Look in js tab and look for "/sitejson' that is the call that gets the info from their server. Hope that helps

Comment: thanks I will try to figure it out with this new information, but where did you go or what did you use to figure out what the method is to retrieve the json? -- also, I don't seem to have a JS tab, I have a Scripts tab but that is empty...thanks for your help so far :)

Comment: I am using firebug in firefox, and by you mentioning that sitejson is what picked up the information made me wonder if that was the url. I did a search on all the javascript files and find an AJAX call to /sitejson with it passing data that held the product id. You should google Jquery AJAX to learn about it. Its pretty cool :)

Comment: will do ! Thanks, this should get me going as you said! :)